# Why CTFrameGetLines return a error result?

Tags: ios

When I set `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`, the number of rows obtained using `CTFrameGetLine` is wrong.

```
self.postDescLabel.attributedText = [UIPostsBrowsingTableViewCell getDescAttrbutedString:self.post.desc];
self.postDescLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

...

```
CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frameRef);
```

The count of lines is wrong. Who can help me?

Comment: what is wrong? there are no details, what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: Because I need the text to be omitted when it is outside the scope of the label, I need to set NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail after setting the ‘attributedText’. But after that I used the CTFrameGetLines to get the number of rows is wrong, for example, there are actually 6 rows, but only got 4 rows. If I remove the NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail setting, the result is correct. What should I do to achieve both NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail and correct lines through CTFrameGetLines?